# Which factors influence the speed with which a fax is transmitted?

Tags: image, fax, winfax

I have an application which generates files automatically and faxes them, and I am trying to improve its speed.

When I send these files through an application called Classic PhoneTools, the duration is 35-40 seconds. The speed is 14,400 bps, and because I choose the option normal quality (not high quality) Classic PhoneTools says the transmission Mode is Normal.

When I send the same files through my application, the duration is always 50-60 seconds. The speed is 14,400 bps, but the transmission Mode is always HQ (High Quality) even if I am not choosing this.

I tried generating all kinds of jpg, pdf and bmp files, large and small, in color, grayscale or black/white, with larger or smaller resolutions, and the speed only improves when I am shrinking the data so that it gets displayed on half of the page or less. I think Classic Phone Tools obtains the same effect by somehow compressing the data obtained from the file before faxing it.

What type of file, with what characteristics, should I generate in order to obtain the optimum faxing speed? Code samples in C# would be excellent.

Comment: The *input format* wont matter, sending HQ delivers more data so takes more time

Comment: That makes perfect sense, the only problem is that I can't find a way to set Normal instead of HQ. I tried applications like SnappyFax, VentaFax or FaxTalk, I also tried FAXCOMLib, and all of them seem to default to HQ without any alternative. Classic Phone Tools is the only one which asks for Normal or HQ. Do you know how I could choose Normal instead of HQ?

Comment: The content of the page has a direct effect on the amount of data needed and how much time to send it. If you have color/grayscale images being dithered to make bitonal you will get much larger files and slower transmission times.